# Python open and save Excel file. Do I need to state sleep time?

Tags: python

My Excel file when opened will need 30 seconds to load data from a database.
My script below successfully Open, Wait till data fully loaded then Save and Close Excel file one by one.

So my question is: Does python by default must wait till the workbook is fully load before it move to the next command Save(). And then wait until Save() is completed to execute Close().
I don't mind to put time.sleep(10) but I want to know how python processes the command sequence in this case.

(When I do parsing data from web, I need to command Python to wait for a certain element is loaded. That's why I wonder if I need to instruct Python to do the same with Excel.)

```
files  = ['file1','file2']

path = f'C:\\Users\\Myfolder\\'

import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True

for i in files:
    print(i)
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open( path + str(i)+'.xlsx')
    # time.sleep(25)

    for wb_name in excel.Workbooks:           #list all currently open excel file
        if wb_name.Name ==  str(i)+'.xlsx' :  #Save exact file name
            print("Save workbook:",wb_name.Name)
            wb_name.Save()
            wb_name.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No python by default **do not** wait till the workbook is fully load before it move to the next command Save(). And rushes to the next before Save() is completed to execute Close(). THerefore, I recommend you to put delay time. Usually, the sleep time demands on the machine processing speed. In your case, it should time.sleep(35). The extra five second is just for safety.
for i in files:
print(i)
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open( path + str(i)+'.xlsx')
time.sleep(35) # yes you need it. Otherwise error message will come out.